# TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null. error upon click event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

```
function checkboard(abc:MovieClip)//:Number 
{
    var targetarray:Array= new Array (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14,
                            T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, T23, T24, T25, T26, T27,
                            T28, T29, T30, T31, T32, T33, T34, T35, T36,T37,T38,T39,T40,T41,T42,
                            T43,T44,T45,T46,T47,T48,T49,T50,T51,T52,T53,T54,T55,T56,T57,T58,
                            T59,T60,T61,T62,T63,T64);
    var black:Array= new Array (B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12,B13,B14,B15,B16);
    var red:Array= new Array (R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10,R11,R12,R13,R14,R15,R16);
    //var propertiess:Array = new Array (0);
    //var legal:Array =(targetarray,propertiess);
    var i:Number = 0;
    var j:Number=0;

    var loh:Number;
    for (i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        if(targetarray[i].hitTestObject(black[j]))
        {
        trace("black peice on ",targetarray[i+1]);
        }
        if(j>18){
            j=18;
        }else{
        j++;
        }

    }
}
```

This is the function that the is causing the error, it seems to be on  this line `if(targetarray[i].hitTestObject(black[j]))`.

However, I do not see why exactly this wouldn't work, the `B[j]` pieces are movie clips and the `T[i]` movie clips are where the black checkers pieces are allowed to move on the checkerboard.

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: It's easy to diagnose such a problem. Put **trace(i,j);** before the error line, so you will know the values of **i** and **j** that produce the error.

Comment: @Organis The error wouldn't even allow me to trace anything , now that i see the error i understand why thank you anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you have 16 elements in your `black` array,  but you allow your `j` var to go up to `18`. So in your for loop, when you do `black[j]`,  it will be `undefined` when `j` has a value of `16`, `17`, or `18`

A safer way to code this, would be along these lines:

```
 //use targetArray.length to only loop to the amount of items in the array
 for(i=0;i<targetArray.length;i++){
    if(targetarray[i].hitTestObject(black[j]))
    {
        //not sure why you're adding 1 here?  This would be null if 'i' is the last number in the loop
        //remember, arrays are 0 based, so `T1` is actually targetArray[0]
        trace("black peice on ",targetarray[i+1]);
    }

    //only increment j if the result is still less than the length of black array.
    if(j < black.length - 1){
        j++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Eww, you spoiled my teaching how to track such a problem down (T_T)

Comment: @Organis: You really should place answers as answers, rather than comments.   *"Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information"* (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Answering in the comments also leads to questions with no accepted answer, which creates noise for people eager to help who only end up wasting their time by finding them already answered ambiguously.

Comment: @Atriace True, but my comment is not an answer. It's an educating push. I put answers as answers when they are informative and useful. Thanks for your concern though.

Comment: Thank you so much, The cause of the actual error was that my forloop was going to 64 when it should have stopped on 63, still getting used to AS3 this is my first attempt at it. Thanks again!

Comment: As it's written in your question, your for loop will stop at 63,  but you do i+1 inside it, so that would make the value 64.   Glad you figured it all out!